# OptionsPattern Confusion

Tags: options, optional-arguments

I want to use the whole options pattern as the argument for HTTPRequest's "Query" parameter, but I'm not sure how to use them. When I run the following code:

```
Options[f] = {a -> a0, b -> b0}
f[x_, y : OptionsPattern[]] := (
  {x, y})
f[1]
```

The output is {1} when I want {1, {a -> a0, b -> b0}}

How can this be done? Thank you

EDIT: is it literally just:

```
Options[f] = {a -> a0, b -> b0}
f[x_, y : OptionsPattern[]] := (
  {x, Options[f]})
f[1]
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `f[x, a->a0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `y` as a variable:

```
f[x_, y_: OptionsPattern[]] := ({x, Options[f]});
```

Comment: Hmm...I thought I had tried that. Thank you though.

Comment: * Now i'm getting "URLParse::nvldval: OptionsPattern[] is not a valid value"

Comment: The first example worked the first time I tried it, but not f[1] is returning `{1, OptionsPattern[]}`. The second solutions works though.

Comment: This isn't actually complete. `y` is never used. Something like `f[x_, y: OptionsPattern[]] := ({x, Flatten@{y, Options[f]}});` is necessary. Also you don't want `y_: OptionsPattern[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you do want to support options, I would do something like the following:

```
Options[f] = {a -> a0, b -> b0};

f[x_, y:OptionsPattern[]] := {x, DeleteDuplicatesBy[Flatten[{y, Options[f]}], First]}
```

For example:

```
f[1]

f[2, a->1]
```

> {1, {a -> a0, b -> b0}}
>
> {2, {a -> 1, b -> b0}}

Comment: This was the first way I though of, but I passed it over thinking that the code assumes the default behavior of options won't change.  It seems highly unlikely that it would change, but I felt `OptionValue[]` takes care of the default way for me automatically, whether or not the behavior changes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Note: You would want `y` not `y_` in `f[x_, y : OptionsPattern[]] := ...`, but you can leave it out altogether. Compare [`Pattern` (`y :`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) and [`Optional` (`y_ :`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html).

```
ClearAll[f]; (* don't forget to clear old definitions! *)
Options[f] = {a -> a0, b -> b0};
f[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{opts = Options[f][[All, 1]]},
   {x, Thread[opts -> OptionValue[opts]]}];
f[1, b -> c0, b -> d0]

(*  {1, {a -> a0, b -> c0}}  *)
```